# Modifying the media-template.php file, the right way?

Tags: gallery, media-settings, core-modifications, media-modal

The `[gallery]` shortcode accepts the `columns='0'` as an attribute so that it doesn't insert any breaks in the HTML between gallery items, however this option is not available in Gallery Settings interface ("Add Media" pop-up when editing pages/posts).

I've located the code in `wp-includes\media-template.php` line 396 to 406;

```
<label class="setting">
    <span><?php _e('Columns'); ?></span>
    <select class="columns" name="columns"
        data-setting="columns">
        <?php for ( $i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++ ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>" <?php selected( $i, 3 ); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html( $i ); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
</label>
```

I don't want to directly edit a core file but I would like to add `<option value="0">Responsive</option>` to that list. What's the best way to do that without editing core files? I was thinking some kind of filter, although I'm not too familiar with them.

Comment: Might this be something that should be submitted as a bug/patch in Trac?

Comment: There is no "right" way to hack a Core file as an end user, but as @ChipBennett suggests, you could fix the problem and submit a patch.

Comment: So then is there a way to modify (even if it's not the "right" way) outside of the core files?

Comment: Please do not touch wordpress core files!
This is very important thing.
You need to find some filters for this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You're in a pretty good pickle here.

There are a couple things you can do as far as I can tell. Both of them are a little tricky.

**Recommended**

The one I would recommend would be to make use of the `do_action('print_media_templates')` at the bottom of that file. It's not perfect, but you could add in an additional field here to take care of the responsive aspect you want to add.

**Possible, but not recommended**

Another option is to actually modify the actions that are being set in `/wp-includes/media.php` lines 2022-2024. Check this out:

```
function custom_print_media_templates() {
  remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_print_media_templates' );
  remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_print_media_templates' );
  remove_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', 'wp_print_media_templates' );

  add_action( 'admin_footer', 'custom_print_media_templates' );
  add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_print_media_templates' );
  add_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', 'custom_print_media_templates' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_media', 'custom_print_media_templates' );
```

You would then have to go create a function called `custom_print_media_templates()` that mirrors the one in `wp-includes/media-template.php`. The problem here is that any changes to WordPress core for this file would need to be replicated in your file. That's why I don't recommend this path.

Comment: very good thinking